# Type 'string' is not assignable to type enum error

Tags: json, angular, enums, rxjs, observable

I have an interface as follows:

```
export interface Preferences {
  theme: Theme;
}
```

with `Theme` being defined as an enum:

```
export enum Theme {
  dark = 'dark',
  light = 'light'
}
```

Suppose I have a JSON file as follows:

```
{
  "theme": "light"
}
```

Suppose also that I want to use it in a service as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Preferences } from '../models/preferences';
import prefExample from '../../assets/preferences.json';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getPreferences(): Observable<Preferences> {
    return of(prefExample);
  }
}
```

When I try and run the above code, it tells me:

```
Types of property 'theme' are incompatible.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Theme'.
```

Comment: `prefExample as Preferences`? Or write something that takes the JSON and returns `Preferences`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is valid JSON data of Preferences, you can just tell TypeScript compiler to use `prefExample` object as `Preferences`, like this:

```
getPreferences(): Observable<Preferences> {
    return of(prefExample as Preferences);
}
```

Comment: TS2352: Conversion of type '{ theme: string; }' to type 'Preferences' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
It looks like I should convert it to `unknown` and then to `Preferences`. Why is this necessary?

Comment: What version of typescript do you use? I checked the code using `~3.8.3` and it's compiled without any error. Also I used import like this `import * as prefExample from '../../assets/preferences.json'` because without `export` you can't import default